# javafx: set different Node Orientation for labels in GridPane

Tags: java, javafx

I have a GridPane and I want one label to span from ***left to right***, while the other label to span from ***right to left***. However, I just cannot get this working. I can set node orientation for the GridPane itself but not for the individual labels.

This is what I have so far:

```
GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
...
// upper left corner of grid pane
Label label1 = new Label("left to right");
label1.setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
gridPane.add(label1, 0, 0,7,1);

// bottom right corner of grid pane
Label label2 = new Label("right to left");
label2.setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
gridPane.add(label2, 2, 9,8,1);
```

**UPDATE:** Since GridPane default node orientation is from left to right, label1  is actually fine. Problem is with my label2. I want it to span from right to left such that regardless of the length of the text, it always starts at the bottom rightmost corner.

An ideal example (3 X 10) would be:

```
|Label1          |
|                |
|          Label2|
```

Ideally, if Label2 span the grids from right to left and if the length of the text in the label increases, it would look like this:

```
|Label1          |
|                |
|      Label2Long|
```

But right now, what I am getting is this:

```
|Label1          |
|                |
|  Label2Long    |     <- I want to get rid of the space between the label and the right border
```

Comment: I'm not sure `nodeOrientation` is the property you are looking for. What are you actually wanting the result of this to be?

Comment: Please see edits. Let me know if I am not explaining it properly.

Comment: You are talking about alignment, not orientation, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: Yes. I kept thinking it as orientation that's why overlooked the term `alignment` when reading the doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`nodeOrientation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#nodeOrientationProperty) has nothing to do with alignment, which is what you really want here.

I think you want

```
GridPane.setHalignment(label2, HPos.RIGHT);
```

The Javadocs for `GridPane` describe how to use all these settings in a lot of detail.